# Trac and SVN Ticket Updates on Windows

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn-server

I am trying to automatically update tickets when I commit a change set on Windows but a little unsure how to do this.

The instructions here don't really offer me much help:

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#can-trac-automatically-update-a-ticket-when-i-commit-a-changeset

Was wondering whether someone could quickly let me know in a step by step manner ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84178/how-do-i-implement-the-post-commit-hook-with-trac-svn-in-a-windows-environment which seems to answer your question.